# 'PolymorphicQuerySet' object has no attribute 'provisioning_set'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have some tables :

```
class Site(models.Model):

company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
site_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=SITE_TYPES, default=AIRCRAFT,)
tailnumber = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, unique=True)
customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)


class Terminal(PolymorphicModel):

created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
tracker = FieldTracker()

class Provisioning(PolymorphicModel):

terminal = models.ForeignKey(Terminal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
usergroup = models.ForeignKey(Usergroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
threat_monitoring = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
```

I run a query:

```
asset = Site.objects.get(id=site_id)
```

In the debugger I get:

> terminal_set which return all related tables of the Terminal model

so far good....

In the same terminal_set is in the provisoning_set ,

I try to query this object site.terminal_set.model.provisioning_set

```
 site.terminal_set.provisioning_set.model.first()
```

This is the exact path!

Why it response with
'PolymorphicQuerySet' object has no attribute 'provisioning_set'

Comment: is `site` an `Site` instance? Or you meant `Site` in your query

Comment: `terminal_set` is a manager, so you can't use `provisioning_set` here. You first need to get a single `terminal` object before being able to use `provisioning_set`, so something like: `site.terminal_set.first().provisioning_set.first()`